# Cognos Report Studio - An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='0'

Tags: report, reporting, cognos, cognos-10

I am working on a list report. The last time I checked it was running perfectly. Today, I run it, it doesn't work and I get this error message :

> An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlOpenResult' status='0'.

This message doesn't  say a lot. Does any one know an error with status 0 can be caused by what?

Thanks !

Comment: In your report, when you get that error, hopefully there's a `Details` link below it, or something like that.  If not, you'll need to dig out the error from your server logs or your audit db, if you have one.

Comment: Thank you! I am still digging.